# Using Angular's UI-router, how can we make sure the new version of the html partial views are used, rather than the cached version?

Tags: angularjs, caching, gruntjs, angular-ui-router

We use Angular's ui-router in an application. We're running into a problem with cache. When we deploy changes, the old HTMl is still used for partial views until the user does a hard refresh. What's worse, the user has to do a hard refresh in every state in order to get that partial view to update.

We use grunt for our build, and have grunt tasks that version our javascript, css, images, etc so the new version is guaranteed to be used. However, I can't find any such grunt task to do the same thing for the html pages.

We've tried setting the main html page to no-cache but that hasn't seemed to help, plus we do want cache to work in general, just not after a new deploy.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The only thing I can think of is to write a grunt task that versions the html files, and then go through our state definitions and update every templateUrl to point to the appropriate version. To make this harder, we have views that are included in other views, not defined in a state, so we'd have to loop through all our .html files as well and make the appropriate updates.

Anyone else have issues with this? Any suggestions?

Comment: I've just switched to ui-router to try to solve this as well.  Did you have any luck?  Thanks.

Comment: We ended up writing our own grunt task to append a buildID to every templateUrl in our state definitions. Haven't made it into a package yet, but I could stick the code somewhere if you're intersted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI router has a component called $templateFactory that loads templates via $http / $templateCache in angular. And $templateCache has a removeAll() method.

So in your app.run stage you can do something like:

```
yourApp.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.removeAll();    
}])
```

Make sure you set some flag for every deployment though, so it doesn't clear the template cache on every refresh.

Comment: This seems like the best approach. Much more straight forward than our custom grunt task that adds buildID to a million places in our code. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some people prefer appendind buildID at the end of html file requests.

`templateUrl : 'path/to/myhtml.html?buildId='+buildID;`

Comment: Yeah, we're thinking we may need to do that. Problem is we need to update our app.js file that defines our states with the new buildID on all our paths to templates, and need to do that.